# Почему когда добавляю в line.split() параметр => не работает list(set(keywords) & set(t_word)

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть код:

```
text = ('Моя програма не працюе, тому що...')

keywords = []
with open('ukr_words.txt', encoding='windows-1251') as f:
    for line in f:
        #for word in line.split('=>' and ','):
        for word in line.split():
            keywords.append(word.strip())
print(keywords)

t_word = text.split()
print(t_word)

result=list(set(keywords) & set(t_word))
print(result)
```

Он выводит ожидаемый результат:

```
C:\Users\46456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe F:/GD/dev_ri/module_files.py
['працюе,', 'робить', '=>', 'работает;', 'це', '=>', 'это;']
['Моя', 'програма', 'не', 'працюе,', 'тому', 'що...']
['працюе,']
```

Но когда делаю так:

```
    text = ('Моя програма не працюе, тому що...')
    keywords = []
    with open('ukr_words.txt', encoding='windows-1251') as f:
        for line in f:
            #for word in line.split('=>' and ','):
            for word in line.split('=>'):
                keywords.append(word.strip())
    print(keywords)
    t_word = text.split()
    print(t_word)
    result=list(set(keywords) & set(t_word))
    print(result)
```

Выдает пустой список result:

```
    C:\Users\46456\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe F:/GD/dev_ri/module_files.py
    ['працюе, робить', 'работает;', 'це', 'это;']
    ['Моя', 'програма', 'не', 'працюе,', 'тому', 'що...']
    []
```

И вопрос по ходу дела: Как сделать так что бы вместо *працюе,* выводилось *працюе*? Тут нужно писать условие на игнор запятой?

Answer (score 1):

Вы вероятно не заметили, что во втором случае (`.split('=>')`) вы получили в переменной `keywords` список не из 7 отдельных слов, а только из этих 3 элементов:

> ```
> працюе, робить 
>  работает; це 
>  это;
> ```

Значит, `result` как пересечение этого списка со списком отдельных слов

> ```
> ['Моя', 'програма', 'не', 'працюе,', 'тому', 'що...']
> ```

будет пустым.

---

*Объяснение:*

Когда примените `.split()`, разложение для пустых знаков выдает правильно отдельные слова:

```
In[1]: 'працюе, робить => работает; це => это;'.split()
Out[1]: ['працюе,', 'робить', '=>', 'работает;', 'це', '=>', 'это;']
In[2]: for el in _:
   ...:     print(el)
```

> ```
> працюе,
> робить
> =>
> работает;
> це
> =>
> это;
> ```

---

Но когда примените `.split('=>')`, строка разделяется *только для пары символов `=>`*, значит, **уже не работает разложение для пустых знаков на отдельные слова:**

```
In[3]: 'працюе, робить => работает; це => это;'.split('=>')
Out[2]: ['працюе, робить ', ' работает; це ', ' это;']
In[4]: for el in _:
   ...:     print(el)
   ...:
```

> ```
> працюе, робить 
>  работает; це 
>  это;
> ```

---

Что касается устранения запятой за словом:

```
if word.endswith(','):
    word = word[:-1]
```

или

```
word = word[:-1] if word.endswith(',') else word
```